# How can I write a stored procedure in pgScript?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, pgadmin

Is it possible to create a stored procedure with `pgScript` in its body? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `pgScript` is only available inside pgAdmin3.

Comment: For information about what languages are available, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xplang.html

Comment: That's a very helpful list as it contains all actively developed, supported and officially distributed procedural languages. Unfortunately it's not complete - there're more PLs e.g. [PL/Java](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pljava/), [PL/R](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/) and [others](http://pgfoundry.org/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=311). Arguably some of them are abandoned, inactive, etc.

Comment: There is a link on that page to an "External Projects" page at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/external-projects.html which has a link to external Procedural Languages at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/external-pl.html -- which does include the PLs you mention and some others.  It does not include all of the ones on the pgfoundry page you cite, though.